# Derivatives - optimization (minimum of a function)

Tags: derivatives, optimization

For which points of $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ the sum of the distances to $(2, 0)$ and $(-2, 0)$ is minimum?

Initially, I did $d = \sqrt{(x-2)^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x+2)^2 + y^2}$, and, by replacing $y^2 = 25 - x^2$,

I got $d = \sqrt{-4x + 29} + \sqrt{4x + 29}$, which derivative does not return a valid answer.

Where did I commit a mistake?

Thank you!!

Comment: One have to test the interval boundaries i.e. $-5$ and $5$ along with the roots of derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better readability,    $$S=\sqrt{29+4x}+\sqrt{29-4x}$$

$$\dfrac{dS}{dx}=\dfrac2{\sqrt{29+4x}}\cdot4-\dfrac2{\sqrt{29-4x}}\cdot4$$

For the extreme values of $S,$ we need $\dfrac{dS}{dx}=0\implies29+4x=29-4x\iff x=0$

Comment: Therefore the two points are $(0,5)$ and $(0,-5)$, i.e. the two points of the circle that are also on the line segment bisector of $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$.